# How do I randomly select an item from a Vector in Julia?

Tags: random, julia

Suppose I have a `Vector` like:

```
["Cat", "Dog", "Chicken", "Caribou"]
```

How can I uniformly randomly select an item?

Answer (score 13):

It's as simple as

```
v=["Cat", "Dog", "Chicken", "Caribou"]
rand(v)
```